# WP_Custom_Media_Control | Give ID to media file

Tags: uploads, media, theme-customizer

I created a custom media control (WP_Customize_Media_Control) into which I upload a file.

I want to give it a specific ID so I can refer to it in various places in my theme.

Is it possible to do so? If so, how?

Thanks a lot in advance! This is literally the most important user file in my theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The setting associated with the media control will have the ID for the attachment stored as its value. Assuming you have registered a setting for your control like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'resume', array(
    'type' => 'option',
    // ...
) );
```

Then you would obtain the attachment ID just by reading from the option, like: `get_option( 'resume' )`.